# Using list specification in NSum

Tags: numerics, warning-messages, summation

The below gives the right answer for summing values from a list (as opposed to a mathematical function) but throws out a warning stating that "k cannot be used for list specification".

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
NSum[list[[k]], {k, 1, 4}]
```

Why does it work at all then, and what's the right way to do it?

Comment: Use `Sum` rather than `NSum`: `Sum[list[[k]], {k, 1, 4}]`; or `list // Most // Total`

Comment: Ah I knew I should have specified more ... I need NSum because I want to use WynnExtrapolation as Method, which Sum does not support.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of where `WynnExtrapolation` is required.

Comment: I think the precise question is: is there no way to get NSum to work on a list? The MWE list of coefficients I have in mind is `list = Table[
   SeriesCoefficient[Series[BesselJ[0, t]^2, {t, 0, 10}], k], {k, 0, 
    10, 2}]`

Comment: `NSum` worked with the `List`, it just gave a warning (which can be suppressed by `Quiet` or turning `Off` the specific message).

Comment: Yes, that it works with a warning was already mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapted from the docs for [`NSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSum.html):

```
f[n_] := Exp[-1/(n + 1)];
list = Table[If[n == 1, f[1], f[n] - f[n - 1]], {n, 1., 10^5}];
ff[n_Integer] := list[[n]];

NSum[ff[n], {n, 1, ∞}, Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]
(*  1.00008  *)
```

Comment: Note: The OP's `NSum[list[[n]], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]` works, but slowly, because, I suspect, the `list` is copied multiple times.  There is no such problem with `ff[n]`.

Answer (score 2):

From the "Details" section of [`NSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSum.html):

> NSum first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates f
>   with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the
>   result numerically.

So basically (if I'm understanding this correctly), `NSum` is trying to evaluate `list[[k]]` (with `k` as a symbol) at some point, which is why the message appears.

A better way to do it is as @Bob Hanlon commented:

```
Sum[list[[k]], {k, 1, 4}];
```

or:

```
list // Most // Total
```

Answer (score 2):

The interpretation [given by Anne](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161255/280) is correct, you can reproduce the error message simply by evaluating

```
list[[k]]
```

> During evaluation of In[5]:= Part::pkspec1: The expression k cannot be used as a part specification.
>
> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[[k]]
> ```

One workaround is to use `Indexed` instead of `Part`:

```
NSum[Indexed[list, k], {k, 1, 4}]
```

> ```
> 10.
> ```